# Big ugly play button on FireFox or IOS

Tags: ios, firefox, video, media-player

Does anyone know how to get rid of this big ugly PLAY button on FireFox or IOS when I add a video background to my Web site?

[image: Ugly Play Button]

I tried adding all types of CSS, such as what I am posting here without success.  I am out of ideas on my end.  None of these CSS entries made a difference and the Button is still displayer as a nuisance.

```
        video:no-button {
        display: none !important;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -9999;
    }

    video::-webkit-media-controls {
        display: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -9999;
    }

    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
        display: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -9999;
    }

    video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
        display: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -9999;
    }

    video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
        display: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -9999;
    }

/* This used to work for the parent element of button divs */
/* But it does not work with newer browsers, the below doesn't hide the play button parent div */

*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* Old shadow dom for play button */

*::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* New shadow dom for play button */

/* This one works! */

*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Here is the video object call that I am using:

```
<video poster="~/video/Bubbles596_150_2.gif" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="~/video/1059946499-hd_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Please post any relevant HTML

Comment: I added the HTML code that I am using.  Thank you for your recommendations and support.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `playsinline` with `webkit-playsinline` in your `<video>` tags?

Comment: Yes, no change.  The big ugly play is still visible.

Comment: Alright, are you using any third-party CSS files that could be overwriting your `::-webkit` styles?

Comment: I just updated every webkit to important and no change.  What could be keeping this button visible on mobile devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235521/discussion-between-william-and-johnny).